# Apple Production iOS Push Services certificate is not working for app distribution

Tags: ios, objective-c, push, distribution

Push notification is working fine when I was using the development provisioning profile and development push certificate.

But when I have builded my app with adhoc provisioning profile inorder to do the distribution via testflightapp.

Person who install my app via the testflightapp didn't get any push notification. I also changed the push certification to production certification with the server.

I don't understand why the push notification is not working with my testflight distribution.

This is what I understand. If there is anything wrong please correct me.

```
   Apple Development iOS Push Services Certification use for development.
```

Push notification should works when the app was build with the development provisioning profile.

```
   Apple Production iOS Push Services Certification use for production and distribution.
```

Push notification should works when the app was build with the adhoc or appstore provisioning profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device tokens are different between development and production, have you changed it?

Comment: The device token should be different because when the user install the app via the testflight (distribution) . At first time the app always asking user to send the push notification so, the production device token is saved to the server. And the server use this device token to generate the payload before sending to the apple push service.

Comment: @user350524 According to Apple's suggestion, device token could changed when user upgrade os, so it should not save token just at first time, you can save old one and compare new one, then decide to update it or not.